# Calculate center of mass row-wise in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, apply

I want to calculate the center of mass (cm) row-wise for a pandas data frame (it is about 4000 rows x 7100 columns). The index of my rows are of type string and the values are numeric only. So basicially my data frame is something like this - just much bigger:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'name':'aaa', 'c2':100, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}, {'name':'bbb','c2':110, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}, {'name':'ccc','c2':120, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df = df.set_index('name')

       c2  c3  c4
name             
aaa   100  20  10
bbb   110  20  10
ccc   120  20  10
```

In R I would use this (my matrix is called m and has the same structure as the data frame above):

```
cm <- apply( m, 1, function(x) sum( x*(1:length(x)) ) / sum(x) )
```

It should be rather easy to write a function that calculates the cm and then apply it row-wise to my data frame, but somehow I am not understanding this. My Python skills are very limited. I do not yet understand the syntax how I could basically iterate over the elements of the row to get the cm.

Comment: *when my - in this case - matrix is called m* ... It's not clear what `m` is here?

Comment: m would in R be the name of my matrix that looks basically like my data frame posted above, sorry for not being clear. I tried to make in more clear in the post now.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that `pandas` was the wrong choice... Look at `numpy` for handling your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.apply` method of pandas

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'name':'aaa', 'c2':100, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}, {'name':'bbb','c2':110, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}, {'name':'ccc','c2':120, 'c3': 20, 'c4':10}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df = df.set_index('name')

def series_sum(pd_series):
    return np.sum(np.dot(pd_series.values, np.asarray(range(1, len(pd_series)+1)))/np.sum(pd_series))

df.apply(series_sum, axis=1)
```

Comment: That looks already very much like what I am looking for. However, if I run it I just get 1 for all rows (and it is of type integer, although one would expect floats). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So i now checked the the nominator (`np.sum(np.inner(pd_series.values, np.asarray(range(1, len(pd_series)+1))))`) and the denominator (`np.sum(pd_series)`) and they give exactly what I expect, so I found that the division itself i causing my problem. If I convert nominator and denominator into floats before divison I get the wanted results. Thank you very much!